# Bashscript error in Ubuntu: awk: line 1: regular expression exceeds implementation size limit

Tags: java, regex, bash, awk, processbuilder

I am trying to apply this code on an annotated file generated by snpEff:
(My OS is Ubuntu)

```
grep -v '^##' /home/zee/fdr_vs_wt.snp.annotated.vcf | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "; OFS=" "} $1~/SL2.50chch/ || $10~/^1\/1/ && ($11~/^1\/0/ || $11~/^0\/0/ || $11~/^0\/1/) && $1~/^[0-9X]*$/ && /splice_acceptor_variant|splice_donor_variant|splice_region_variant|stop_lost|start_lost|stop_gained|missense_variant|coding_sequence_variant|inframe_insertion|disruptive_inframe_insertion|inframe_deletion|disruptive_inframe_deletion|exon_variant|exon_loss_variant|exon_loss_variant|duplication|inversion|frameshift_variant|feature_ablation|duplication|gene_fusion|bidirectional_gene_fusion|rearranged_at_DNA_level|miRNA|initiator_codon_variant|start_retained/ {$3=$7=""; print $0}' | sed 's/  */ /g' | awk '{split($9,a,":"); split(a[2],b,","); if (b[1]>b[2] || $1~/SL2.50ch/) print $0}' > /home/zee/fdr_vs_wt.raw.vcfmutantbulk.cands2.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
awk: line 1: regular expression /splice_acc ... exceeds implementation size limit
```

Can anyone please help? I know this question was asked by another person a while ago but I am not technically strong and I did not understand the solutions given. Thanks in advance.

I also intend to use this code in my Java GUI later, I will be using ProcessBuilder to run it with the following code:

```
    speciesFastaVersionCH = "SL2.50";

    String longInputcmd4b = "ch/ || $10~/^1\\/1/ && ($11~/^1\\/0/ || $11~/^0\\/0/ || $11~/^0\\/1/) && $1~/^[0-9X]*$/ && /splice_acceptor_variant|splice_donor_variant|splice_region_variant|stop_lost|start_lost|stop_gained|missense_variant|coding_sequence_variant|inframe_insertion|disruptive_inframe_insertion|inframe_deletion|disruptive_inframe_deletion|exon_variant|exon_loss_variant|exon_loss_variant|duplication|inversion|frameshift_variant|feature_ablation|duplication|gene_fusion|bidirectional_gene_fusion|rearranged_at_DNA_level|miRNA|initiator_codon_variant|start_retained/ {$3=$7=\"\"; print $0}' | sed 's/  */ /g' | awk '{split($9,a,\":\"); split(a[2],b,\",\"); if (b[1]>b[2] || $1~/";
    StringBuilder cmd4 = new StringBuilder().append("\"").append("grep -v '^##' ").append(outputFilecmd3).append(" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=\" \"; OFS=\" \"} $1~/").append(speciesFastaVersionCH).append(longInputcmd4b).append(speciesFastaVersionCH).append("ch/) print $0}' > ").append(outputFilecmd5).append("\"");



    System.out.println("Here is cmd4:" + cmd4.toString());
    String [] gatkArray1 = cmd1.split(" ");
    String [] gatkArray2 = cmd2.split(" ");
    String [] gatkArray3 = {"bash", "-c", cmd3};


    String [][] gatkArrays = {gatkArray1, gatkArray2, gatkArray3};


    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(gatkArray3);
    pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: From a security perspective, btw, this is a really, **really** horrible idea. As in, I was recently involved in development of code-quality guidelines that specifically say never to assemble code interpreted by a shell via string concatenation under any circumstances whatsoever. Real-world exploitable security vulnerabilities caused by the practice are not hard to come by -- search for "shell injection vulnerability" if you're looking for examples.

Comment: Pass your data **out-of-band** from your code. That is, you can run `['bash', '-c', 'echo "First argument is $1"', 'this is $0', 'this is $1']` and the values passed after the script remain data rather than being parsed as code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into this as well. I am developing an open source tool though, and being a newbie the level of exasperation is directly proportional to not understanding what people say on this forum && code not working 99.99% of the time && the amount of hours it takes just to be able to make a commandline code (written by someone else!) work through java :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `awk` doesn't support regular expressions of that length.

Specifically, you are using `mawk` where the max regex limit is 400 including the `//`:

```
$ true | mawk "/$(printf '%397s')/"
(no output)

$ true | mawk "/$(printf '%398s')/" 
mawk: line 1: regular expression /           ... exceeds implementation size limit
```

You can either rewrite your awk script to use shorter regex literals (the maximum size guaranteed by POSIX is [256 bytes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_02)), or switch to an implementation like `gawk` where the only limit is Linux's maximum argument size of 128KiB:

```
$ true | gawk "/$(printf '%131069s')/"
(no output)

$ true | gawk "/$(printf '%131070s')/"
bash: /usr/bin/gawk: Argument list too long
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I installed gawk in bash, replaced the first awk by gawk and it worked. Really appreciate the help <3